# how to write this statement in linq to sql

Tags: linq

```
SELECT TOP (5) 
    Sales.Product, Sales.Product_Price, COUNT(*) AS CNT, 
    Products.Category, Products.IMG_URL, Products.Rate_Avg
FROM          
    Sales 
INNER JOIN
    Products ON Sales.Product = Products.Product
GROUP BY      
    Sales.Product, Sales.Product_Price, 
    Products.Category, Products.IMG_URL, Products.Rate_Avg
HAVING        
    (COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY      CNT DESC
```

Comment: You haven't shown us what you have tried. Please post your attempt to translate this to linq so that we can assist you. Asking for us to do this for you is usually not how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of that query has a 1-to-1 correspondence to the equivalent linq-to-sql expression.  Though the `TOP (5)` part needs to be added to the end.

```
(from s in db.Sales
join p in db.Products on s.Product equals p.Product
group s by new { s.Product, s.Product_Price, p.Category, p.IMG_URL, p.Rate_Avg } into g
where g.Count() > 1
orderby g.Count() descending
select new
{
    g.Key.Product,
    g.Key.Product_Price,
    CNT = g.Count(),
    g.Key.Category,
    g.Key.IMG_URL,
    g.Key.Rate_Avg,
}).Take(5)
```

Comment: But how can I show it  on asp.net page in a table I'm using foreach